# app Radio Online

Tags: stream, mediaplayer, radio, play

[image: Radio Cloud Music]

Buenas a ver si alguien me echa una mano con Android Studio 2020 3.1 soy novato y me gustaría saber como programas los botones de play -- pausa -- salir -- actualizar, a parte de los botones de las redes sociales. Lo he intentado con varios post que he visto pero imposible ponerlo en marcha tuve que poner un WevView con una Url para por lo pronto poderla hacer funcionar. Tambien como puedo que se actualize la caratula y el titulo cada 10 segundos. Muchas gracias y perdonar por ser tan torpe. Saludos a todos.

Este es el MainActivity.java:

**http://www.cloud-music.es/MainActivity_java.txt**

Comment: hola, de partida para que te podamos ayudar bien necesitamos que pongas el código que tienes, con eso vamos a tener una base y vamos a poder ver donde puede estar el error que hace que no te funcionen los botones. Saludos

Comment: Hola buenas, gracias por contestar cual de los archivos necesitas o necesitas todo el código. Un saludo.

Comment: Este es el MainActivity.java:
http://www.cloud-music.es/MainActivity_java.txt

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugerimos revisar [ask], agrega lo que trataste o investigaste en el cuerpo de la pregunta por favor, si agregas enlaces estos pueden no servir en un futuro y serían obsoletos saludos.